# Open child window and redirect parent window

Tags: javascript, redirect, parent-child, new-window

I have a JavaScript that opens a new window when a button is clicked.  It works fine.  But, I want to **re-direct the Parent Window** (i.e. the current page) once the new window is opened.

Here is my script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function OpenWindow() {
    window.open('/My_Folder/file.php',
                'newwindow',
                config='height=670,width=1400,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no');
}
</script>
```

And, the button:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="OpenWindow()">
```

So, in order to be able to re-direct the Parent Window, after the new window has popped up, I added a simple line to my JS function :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function OpenWindow() {
    window.open('/My_Folder/new_file.php', 'newwindow', 
                config='height=670,width=1400,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,location=no,directories=no, status=no');
}

setTimeout(1000, '/My_Folder/PHP/file_2.php');
</script>
```

Meaning, after the new window has popped up, the Parent Window should **re-direct in 1 second.**

But, for some reason, it's not working.

Online searches have only given me solutions for situations involving the reverse :  **re-direct the Parent Window after CLOSING the child-window.**

I want to re-direct the Parent Window after opening a new (child) window.

**UPDATE**

So far, I've tried these 3 ways :

```
   (a)  <script type="text/javascript">
   function OpenWindow()    {
   window.open ('/My_Folder/new_file.php', 'newwindow', 
   config='height=670, width=1400,   
   toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, location=no, 
   directories=no, status=no');
   window.top.location.href = '/My_Folder/PHP/file_2.php'
   }
   </script>


 (b)  <script type="text/javascript">
 function OpenWindow() { window.open('/My_Folder/file.php','newwindow',         
 config='height=670,width=1400,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,
 resizable=no, location=no,directories=no,status=no');
 settimeout( function(){document.location='/My_Folder/PHP/file_2.php'}, 1000    
 );
 }
 </script>


 (c) <script>
     function OpenWindow()    {
    window.open ('/My_Folder/new_file.php', 'newwindow', 'height=670, 
    width=1400, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, 
     location=no, directories=no, status=no');

        window.location = '/My_Folder/PHP/file_2.php';
     }
     </script>
```

Of all these, none are working.

But  **(b)** is the best solution so far, because, at least, **it opens the New (Child) Window**, as it should.  But, it still does not re-direct the Parent Window  :(((

Comment: I don't know much JavaScript, but shouldn't the `setTimeout` line come *inside* the function definition rather than after it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function OpenWindow() { window.open('/My_Folder/file.php','newwindow',
             config='height=670,width=1400,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no');
settimeout( function(){document.location.href='/My_Folder/PHP/file_2.php'}, 1000 );
}
</script>
```

Moves the settimeout into the function and uses it properly, and tells the window to change to a new location.

Comment: Hmmm.............this didn't work.  The new (child) window opened, as it should.  But..........the Parent Window did not re-direct to the new location.

Comment: My apologies, it should be document.location.href='/...';
I'll edit the answer if it will let me.

Answer (score 0):

My javasrcipt isnt too hot, but does this not work ?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function OpenWindow()    {
    window.open ('/My_Folder/new_file.php', 'newwindow', 
      config='height=670, width=1400,   
      toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, location=no, 
      directories=no, status=no');
     window.top.location.href = '/My_Folder/PHP/file_2.php'
     }


</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit.  But, your code gave me a syntax error.  Shouldn't there be  brackets and a semi-colon somewhere here :  '/My_Folder/PHP/file_2.php'  ???